# Deserializing JSON objects: which one to use?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I realized that there are two ways to deserialize JSON as an object.

So assume I had a string `json` containing JSON data, a type called `Name`, and a JavaScriptSerializer called `ser`:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer(typeof(Name));
```

We can deserialize the JSON using

```
ser.Deserialize(json, typeof(Name));
```

or

```
ser.Deserialize<Name>(json);
```

Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: Save yourself the frustration and use json.net:  http://www.newtonsoft.com/json, both Microsoft implementations (JavaScriptSerializer and DataContractSerializer) have weird quirks.

Comment: @Matthew I agree, and use newtonsoft myself - however that library has the effective equivalent of these methods anyway, leading to the same question.

Comment: I know my comment didn't answer the question, but hopefully this will lead OP to use a decent serializer before they waste time on weird issues.

Comment: @Matthew : even Microsoft's team use Json.Net instead of the legacy serializers, so you can't be more right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to start with this type of question is in the [source code itself](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptSerializer.cs,a161828699d90ec4,references).  Here we see:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string input) {
    return (T)Deserialize(this, input, typeof(T), RecursionLimit);
}

public object Deserialize(string input, Type targetType) {
    return Deserialize(this, input, targetType, RecursionLimit);
}
```

This shows that `Deserialize<T>` is a wrapper around [the same internal `Deserialize` function](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptSerializer.cs,2c276f40d76a2782) that the non-typed `Deserialize()` is.  Using it however has the advantage that you get back a known type, rather than an `object`, as it's done the cast for you.

Comment: So, what you're saying is, the two are actually the same, only the first one returns an object of type T and the second one returns an object that we need to cast ourselves?

Comment: use the generic version if possible. It's better to have strongly typed return values instead of a bunch of objects lying around, waiting for you to make a mistake in a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, Deserialize< T> and Deserialize both calls the static JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize() as per the source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptSerializer.cs,a161828699d90ec4,references

Deserialize< T>:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string input) {
        return (T)Deserialize(this, input, typeof(T), RecursionLimit);
    }
```

Deserialize:

```
public object Deserialize(string input, Type targetType) {
        return Deserialize(this, input, targetType, RecursionLimit);
    }
```